# How to display Runtime Statistics in Tensorboard using Estimator API in a distributed environment

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

[This article](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/graph_viz#runtime_statistics) illustrates how to add Runtime statistics to Tensorboard:

```
    run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
    run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
    summary, _ = sess.run([merged, train_step],
                          feed_dict=feed_dict(True),
                          options=run_options,
                          run_metadata=run_metadata)
    train_writer.add_run_metadata(run_metadata, 'step%d' % i)
    train_writer.add_summary(summary, i)
    print('Adding run metadata for', i)
```

which creates the following details in Tensorboard:

[image: Runtime Statistics in Tensorboard]

This is fairly straightforward on a single machine.  How could one do this in a distributed environment using Estimators?

Comment: I am running into the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: hooks is probably the way

Comment: Not yet.  Any pointers on how to do this with hooks?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may use [tf.train.ProfilerHook](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/ProfilerHook). However the catch is that it was released at 1.14.

Example usage:

```
estimator = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(...)
hooks = [tf.train.ProfilerHook(output_dir=model_dir, save_secs=600, show_memory=False)]
estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, hooks=hooks)
```

Executing the hook will generate files `timeline-xx.json` in `output_dir`.

Then open `chrome://tracing/` in chrome browser and load the file. You will get a time usage timeline like below.
[image]

Answer (score 13):

I use the following hook, based on ProfilerHook, to have the estimator output the run metadata into the model directory and inspect it later with Tensorboard.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.training.session_run_hook import SessionRunHook, SessionRunArgs
from tensorflow.python.training import training_util
from tensorflow.python.training.basic_session_run_hooks import SecondOrStepTimer

class MetadataHook(SessionRunHook):
    def __init__ (self,
                  save_steps=None,
                  save_secs=None,
                  output_dir=""):
        self._output_tag = "step-{}"
        self._output_dir = output_dir
        self._timer = SecondOrStepTimer(
            every_secs=save_secs, every_steps=save_steps)

    def begin(self):
        self._next_step = None
        self._global_step_tensor = training_util.get_global_step()
        self._writer = tf.summary.FileWriter (self._output_dir, tf.get_default_graph())

        if self._global_step_tensor is None:
            raise RuntimeError("Global step should be created to use ProfilerHook.")

    def before_run(self, run_context):
        self._request_summary = (
            self._next_step is None or
            self._timer.should_trigger_for_step(self._next_step)
        )
        requests = {"global_step": self._global_step_tensor}
        opts = (tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
            if self._request_summary else None)
        return SessionRunArgs(requests, options=opts)

    def after_run(self, run_context, run_values):
        stale_global_step = run_values.results["global_step"]
        global_step = stale_global_step + 1
        if self._request_summary:
            global_step = run_context.session.run(self._global_step_tensor)
            self._writer.add_run_metadata(
                run_values.run_metadata, self._output_tag.format(global_step))
            self._writer.flush()
        self._next_step = global_step + 1

    def end(self, session):
        self._writer.close()
```

To use it, one creates the estimator instance (my_estimator) as usual, whether it is pre-made one or a custom estimator. The desired operation is called passing an instance of the class above as a hook. For example:

```
hook = MetadataHook(save_steps=1, output_dir=<model dir>)
my_estimator.train( train_input_fn, hooks=[hook] )
```

The run metadata will be placed in the model dir and can be inspected by TensorBoard.