# Using the Tensorflow profiler with tf.Estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I need to use the Tensorflow profiler to profile some code that is running slowly for some reason. Unfortunately, the code in question uses tf.Estimator, so I can't figure out how to inject the run metadata object into the session run() call in order to get the information that the profiler needs.

What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

`tf.estimator` use `tf.train.ProfilerHook` works!

just add a `ProfilerHook` in `TrainSpec` hooks!

```py
hook = tf.train.ProfilerHook(
    save_steps=20,
    output_dir=os.path.join(args.model_dir, "tracing"),
    show_dataflow=True,
    show_memory=True)
hooks = [hook]
train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(
    hooks=hooks,
    input_fn=lambda: input_fn())
```

then, you could get the tracing file like `timeline-{}.json` in `model_dir/tracing`, and open chrome `chrome://tracing` to visual!

refs:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48278275/6494418

Answer (score 2):

`with tf.contrib.tfprof.ProfileContext('/tmp/train_dir', dump_steps=[10]) as pctx:
  estimator.train() # any thing you want to profile`

Then you will get a file at `/tmp/train_dir/profile_10`

Arguments are defined in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/profiler/profile_context.py

Answer (score 0):

Use ProfileContext, as described here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/core/profiler . This allows you to profile without needing to get access to the session.